# Pandas (>=1.3.x) to_xml function (add tree levels)

Tags: python, pandas, lxml

I have installed pandas lasted version (`pip install git+https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas.git`) because it has [to_xml](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_xml.html) function.

I have the following situation:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'shape': ['square', 'circle', 'triangle'],

                   'degrees': [360, 360, 180],

                   'sides': [4, np.nan, 3]})

df.to_xml(root_name= 'root',
    row_name= 'rows')
```

Output:

[image: output]

I have a question:

1- How to save xml with a level_2_root ?

[image]

Comment: You should ask one question at a time. Else the community can't reuse answers easily.

Comment: Ok./ i just deleted the second one.

Comment: I'm looking into it, but it seems "stylesheet" is the parameter you want to use.